# Can't find the position of the last occurrence of a substring

Tags: php

This code works

```
$domains = '.com';
$data = strripos($message, $domains);
return $data;
```

But if I pass an array, it returns false

```
$domains = ['.com', '.cc', '.porno'];

foreach($domains as $domain) {
    $data = strripos($message, $domain);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Your code makes little sense if you want to check your message against all TLD extensions, because it will exit after completing the first iteration. Are you trying to detect the presence of any of these substrings? Or do you need to actually know a position? And then of just one of the possible extensions, or of all of them?

Comment: I want to find a substring

Answer (score 0):

$var = array( 'Madrid', 'París', 'Londres' );

echo end( $var );

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
$string = 'My websites are example.com and example.cc. No porno TLD';
$domains = ['.com', '.cc', '.porno'];

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
  if (strstr($string, $domain)) echo "Found: $domain "; // Case sensitive
  // OR: if (strripos($string, $domain)) echo "Found: $domain "; // Case insensitive
}

// OUTPUT: Found: .com Found: .cc
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's just the positions you're interested in, then how about something like this?

```
<?php

// Random message.
$message = 'Please check our awesome product at awesome.com, and for more stuff go to ourshop.cc. We don\'t deal in porno';

// The TLD extensions you want to find.
$domains = ['.com', '.cc', '.porno'];

// This array will hold all the positions, or FALSE if a TLD was not found.
$tldPositions = [];

// Loop over each TLD and store its last occurring position.
foreach($domains as $domain)
    $tldPositions[$domain] = strripos($message, $domain);

var_dump($tldPositions);

/* $tldPositions now holds
array(3) {
  [".com"]=>
  int(43)
  [".cc"]=>
  int(81)
  [".porno"]=>
  bool(false)
}
*/
```